# Adding WFS layer with OpenLayers

Tags: gis, openlayers, geoserver

I'm trying to add one of the included datasets with geoserver to an openlayers map. I've followed the opengeo tutorials, seen similar thread on here, but I can't seem to crack it. Can somebody take a glance at my code and geoserver setup and tell me where i'm going wrong?

Here's my code:

```
            //WMS map
            world = new OpenLayers.Layer.WMS("Global Imagery", "http://maps.opengeo.org/geowebcache/service/wms", {
                layers : "openstreetmap",
                format : "image/png"
            });
            map.addLayer(world);

            //WFS
            parks = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector("WFS", {
                strategies : [new OpenLayers.Strategy.BBOX()],
                protocol : new OpenLayers.Protocol.WFS({
                    url : "http://localhost:8081/geoserver/wfs",
                    featureType : "medford:parks",
                    featureNS : "http://medford.opengeo.org/medford"
                })
            });

            map.addLayer(parks);

            map.zoomToMaxExtent();
```

GeoServer details:
workspace name = medford, Namespace URI = http://medford.opengeo.org
For the feature type I have tried "parks" and "medford:parks"

The layer is enabled, advertised and has a 30 feature return limit.

I'm struggling to put a simple map together

Thanks,
James

Answer (score 3):

Firstly could you give some more info about any errors that are occuring by using a debugging tool like firebug.  my first guess would be that the geoserver instance is not running on the same domain (this includes a different port on the same domain)  and requests to the server are being blocked by the cross-site scripting restrictions.

If this is the case OpenLayers comes with some example CGI proxy scripts to allow you to proxy the call to geoserver. have a look [here](http://trac.osgeo.org/openlayers/wiki/FrequentlyAskedQuestions#ProxyHost) for more info.

hope that helps, if not maybe post some more info relating to any errors you see.

Comment: you are right - most likely the problem is that wfs-requests are being sent to different domain - http://localhost:8081/

Comment: OK I've now moved my code to http://localhost:8081/apps/index.html and changed my featureNS. I can now see 30 features coming back on the response...<rpid:OBJECTID>25</rpid:OBJECTID><rpid:FIELD_ID>NS/86427/74196</rpid:FIELD_ID><rpid:GROSS_AREA>2.307</rpid:GROSS_AREA>. However I'm not seeing any of the features on my map. When added as WMS I can see them fine. The only other layer is a base WMS.

Comment: this sounds like it coul be unrelated to the openlayers code.  perhaps a styling issue for the layer in geoserver? does the WFS return include location information for the features? if you could add some debug output, like a snippet from the WFS return, in the question above i'll take a look